# Avro support in Flink - scala

Tags: scala, avro, apache-flink

How to read `avro` from `Flink` in `scala`?

Is it the same for batch/stream/table:  `StreamExecutionEnvironment`/ `ExecutionEnvironment` / `TableEnvironment`?

would it be sth like: `val custTS: TableSource = new AvroInputFormat("/path/to/file", ...)`

Below is java avro implementation ref ([connectors](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/batch/connectors.html)), but can't find scala ref anywhere:

```
  AvroInputFormat<User> users = new AvroInputFormat<User>(in, User.class);
  DataSet<User> usersDS = env.createInput(users);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Flink's `InputFormats`, including the `AvroInputFormat`, from the Java as well as the Scala API:

- Streaming & batch: `val avroInputStream = env.createInput(new AvroInputFormat[User](in, classOf[User]))`
- Table API: `tableEnv.registerTable("table", avroInputStream.toTable)`